# How do I change a JavaScript array in place?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I change a JS array in place (like a Ruby "dangerous" method, e.g. with trailing `!`)

**Example:**

If I have this:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3]
```

How can I make this:

```
arr === [2, 4, 6]
```

(assuming I have an appropriate function for doubling numbers) in one step, without making any more variables?

Answer (score 5):

Use `Array.prototype.forEach()` , third parameter is `this` : input array

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.forEach(function(el, index, array) {
  array[index] = el * 2
});
console.log(arr)
```